# Do triggers have a THISROW object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

The example will give a brief explanation of what i'm talking about:

```
 AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
 IF (This.Active = 1) 
      BEGIN
         UPDATE Table2 SET AllActive = 1 WHERE This.ID = Table2.ID
      END
 ELSE
      BEGIN
         UPDATE Table2 SET AllActive = 0 WHERE This.ID = Table2.ID
      END
```

I'm using `this` because that's what i'm looking to do.

Do Triggers have a `this` like javascript?

If not, What's the next best thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common misconception about triggers in SQL Server: they are **NOT** fired per row affected - but by **statement**.

And therefore, when you have a statement that inserts or updates several rows, your `Inserted` (and/or `Deleted`) pseudo tables in the trigger will contain multiple rows. Do **NOT** assume you're dealing with a single row! Such a trigger will fail sooner or later

So in your case, you would probably want to write something like this:

```
  UPDATE t 
  SET AllActive = i.Active
  FROM Inserted i
  INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t 
  ON t.ID = i.ID
```

This will update all rows in the `Table2` table and set the `AllActive` column to the value of `Active`, for each row that's contained in the `Inserted` table (contains the newly inserted rows, and the new values for the updated rows)

Comment: What do you mean "go through them all"? This is a one-pass, set-based update. Your proposed pseudo code is what was trying to process them one row at a time, which is a lot more painful and not the way you typically want to do things in an RDBMS.

Comment: Just thought triggers were more of a per row deal, because even when you're doing multiple rows in one insert, it still has to insert it per row anyway.

Comment: Triggers don't work that way. There is a set of rows in the `deleted` pseudo-table. If you want to treat them one row at a time, you have to use your own cursor for that, but like I said, that's not the most optimal way to do it.